# Don't run second function if first function is ran

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header with a drop down, div, notification box (`#container`) that gets slide toggled. The JavaScript for the drop down box is:

```
$("a.trigger").click(function (event) {
     $('#container').slideToggle(100)
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

I also have a function that closes the div box if I click anywhere outside of the `#container`:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('#container');

    if (!container.is(e.target)) {     
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

When I click on the `a.trigger` it drops down the `#container` and then if I click anywhere outside  the `#container` it properly closes it. But when I click on `a.trigger` while the `#container` is already exposed, it closes it from the second javascript function since `a.trigger` is outside of `#container` but then the first function gets triggered too afterwards and the `#container` slidestoggles down again right after being hidden.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/1013/

I was thinking of making it so that if the first javascript function is called then it will just stop the second one from initiating. How would I approach this? and is there a more conventional approach?

Comment: You can set a simple flag [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/1026/)

Comment: @A1rPun You're not considering the closing of the menu when the user clicks outside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if the target is the `.trigger` or a parent (just in case) like you do in the if :

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('.trigger').length) return;
    var container = $('#container');

    if (!container.is(e.target)) {     
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/1034/

---

The best would be to rework event handler and use `click` on both element, not `mouseup` on one and `click` on the other. Then you can use stop propagation :

```
$("a.trigger").click(function (event) {
    $('#container').slideToggle(100)
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); //Stop the event from bubbling
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $('#container');

    if (!container.is(e.target)) {     
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/1036/

Comment: Good answer. While using a global flag isn't wrong, without one is indeed nicer.

Comment: Reworking and making them both click was definitely better. Along with stop propagation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use [event.stopPropagation()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) and bind both events to click.

```
$("a.trigger").click(function (event) {
         $('#container').slideToggle(100)
         event.stopPropagation();
    });

$(document).click(function (e) {
        $('#container').hide();
    });
```

to make slide up animation: $('#container').slideUp(100);

Answer (score 0):

Does this help some?

```
var opened= false;

$("a.trigger").click(function (event) {
         $('#container').slideToggle(100)
         opened=!opened;
         event.preventDefault();
    });

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $('#container');

        if (!container.is(e.target) && !opened) {     
            container.hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a second boolean in the second function. I tried it with

```
if (!container.is(e.target)&&!$('a.trigger').is(e.target)) {     
        container.hide();
    }
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/1031/

Hope that is what you wanted.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question. You checked the container is not e.target. Why not also check a.trigger is not e.target?

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $('#container');
        var trigger   = $('a.trigger');

        if (!container.is(e.target) && !trigger.is(e.target) ) {     
            container.hide();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMZX2/

Answer (score 0):

Can also check if target is you trigger class

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('#container');      
    if (!container.is(e.target) && !$('.trigger').is(e.target)) {     
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ay4Vg/)**</kbd>

Comment: Why converting the target as a jQuery object in this specific case?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon  good point, just an old habit I guess. Am used to using `$tgt.something`